# How to determine what library is starting service in my app

Tags: android, service

I have implement some libs and realize that there is an service running by my app (See it in apps manager of device settings, the service name is SyncService).

Please tell me how to find out what library started this service.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: before that, how can you say that the service is started by the external library? Does it means in your app's code, you don't have any service implemented?

Comment: if there is any service in your app then it must be there in your app's manifest fille.

Comment: My code does not have any service.